# rasterio mask aborts kernel. Potential issue with format for geojson feature?

Tags: geojson, rasterio

I have a pandas dataframe where each row is a bounding box. i'd like to crop my raster by each feature.

```
       xmin       xmax        ymin        ymax  \
1  398296.6  398301.46  3280997.15  3280998.96   

                                                 box  
1  NEON_D03_OSBS_DP1_398000_3280000_classified_po...
```

I first created a function to create a geojson polygon from each row.

```
def data2geojson(df):
    features = []
    insert_features = lambda X: features.append(
            {"type": "polygon",
                 "coordinates": 
                 [[(float(X["xmin"]),float(X["ymin"])),
                     (float(X["xmax"]),float(X["ymin"])),
                     (float(X["xmax"]),float(X["ymax"])),
                     (float(X["xmin"]),float(X["ymax"])),
                     (float(X["xmin"]),float(X["ymin"]))]]}
        )

    df.apply(insert_features, axis=1)
    return geojson.FeatureCollection(features)
```

such that the output of each row looks like

```
{'type': 'polygon', 'coordinates': [[(398534.16, 3280995.59), (398539.84, 3280995.59), (398539.84, 3280998.99), (398534.16, 3280998.99), (398534.16, 3280995.59)]]}
```

The idea would be then to iterate through features to create the crops

```
out_image,out_transform=mask(img.tile,[features[0]],crop=True)
```

This yields no error message, but just kills the python kernel.

My initial thought is that my format of the geojson is incorrect? I was following [rasterio masking with GeoJSON from file issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238746/rasterio-masking-with-geojson-from-file-issue)

System info

```
3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 30 2018, 00:00:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]

rasterio.__version__
'0.36.0'
```

Edit #1: Looking at other answer, it appears we are looking for a geojson polygon, not feature. Same behavior, simplified the function.

Edit #2: Closed the polygon by providing the initial point as the last coordinate.

Edit #3, in case there was worry that my installation was invalid. I cloned the rasterio repo and ran [this](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio-cookbook/blob/master/recipies/mask_shp.py) example. No issues. From that example, it appears that the features should be a dict, not a geojson polygon directly, which makes sense looking at the source. Revised. No improvement.

Comment: Shouldn't polygon be closed?

Comment: no change, but edited to reflect that try.

Answer (score 1):

It was only evident to me after cloning the rasterio repo and trying itself. The docs say

> ```
>     GeoJSON-like dict representation of polygons that will be used to
>     create the mask.
> ```

My mistake was literally trying to make a geojson object. I succeeded when I just made a dict that looked like a geojson object...just as the docs suggested. Taken literally, it works.

```
def data2geojson(df):
    features = []
    insert_features = lambda X: features.append(
            {"type": "Polygon",
                 "coordinates": 
                 [[(float(X["xmin"]),float(X["ymin"])),
                     (float(X["xmax"]),float(X["ymin"])),
                     (float(X["xmax"]),float(X["ymax"])),
                     (float(X["xmin"]),float(X["ymax"])),
                     (float(X["xmin"]),float(X["ymin"]))]]}
        )
```

Note that case matters! "Polygon"